# How to alternate between fragment containers easily?

Tags: android

I've got a problem that I'm having problems solving. My app has 2 types of fragments. When the app starts, a fragment with main menu is added to a `FrameLayout` that I use as a fragment container. This fragment takes up the entire screen. Then, when I choose one of the items in the menu, a corresponding fragment should be loaded into the container, replacing the menu. However, this fragment must only take 1/4 of the screen from the left, and the space outside is to be used by some other fragment.

I was thinking about making 3 `FrameLayouts`, one for the left side, one for the right and one for the entire screen, but this is going to have problems with fragment transactions, since I would have to keep tabs on which fragments are where and remove them by hand.

Basically what I need is some way to change whether my fragments are loaded into a container that takes up full screen, or a container that takes up only some part of the screen. I probably could do it with tons of trail and error and some code, but I bet there is a really easy way to do this in android that I missed.

Comment: **"...since I would have to keep tabs on which fragments are where and remove them by hand"** : That's kind of how it's meant to be when working with Fragments and that's why they're so versatile. Of course versatility comes at a price and the more Fragments being used and the more complex the different Fragment layouts are, the more complex the "code behind" becomes. It's not compulsory to use Fragments and if you're uncomfortable with handling complex Fragment container layouts then just use different Activities as suggested by howettl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to dynamically load these fragments into the various containers, I would suggest having two different `Activities`.

It sounds like the main menu fragment will only ever appear on its own in full screen.  So, make that a full `Activity` (let's call it `MainMenuActivity`).

The second activity will have two `FrameLayout`s as it's contents, with one taking up 1/4 of the screen and the other taking up the remaining 3/4.  Load this second activity upon choosing a main menu option and populate the fragments in `onCreate()` of the second activity.

Hitting the back button from the second activity will return the user to `MainMenuActivity`.